# Break out delimited string with the same category in a two column table using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a 2 column table that consists of items in the 1st column and color categories in the 2nd, with the item and colors tab-delimited:

```
car blue
bicycle;scooter green
boat yellow
firetruck;airplane;skateboard red
motorcycle black
```

I would like to transform the table/list to read:

```
car blue
bicycle green
scooter green
boat yellow
firetruck red
airplane red
skateboard red
motorcycle black
```

I was thinking that I would need to have a function defined to handle the splitting of the delimited string in column 1 and writing the appropriate category in the 2nd column for each row/line.

I think the logic essentially reads:

```
with open('colors_in.txt', 'rt') as src:
with open('colors_out.txt', 'wt') as dest:

#store column 2 category in a variable and break apart the string at the delimiter in new lines + category
def splitter()
    colorval = (row[1] for row in src)
    for line in src:
        for word in line.split(';'):
            dest.write(word.rstrip() + colorval + '\n')

if ";" in line:
    splitter()
else:
    for line in src:
        dest.write(line)
```

I've looked around for approaches to this problem and saw some pretty complex elements involving numpy and imap() that I'm not really sure how to incorporate. I know the above code is wildly incorrect -- just tried to express as best I could what I want the code to do/accomplish.

Comment: And, would love to know if there are reference books out there that would have examples like this along with their solutions (like a Python cook book of sorts).  There seem to be many...would appreciate recommendations to help narrow the field.

Comment: Do you want to actually change the original file?

Comment: Also is there ever more than one word before the `;`

Comment: @Padraic - I don't want to change the original file.  Create a new file with the transformation.  And there could be multiple words delimited by `;` -- like `big firetruck;fast airplane;broken skateboard` but I think the solution proposed by Anand below takes that into account since he's defined that entire string as a column. Could be wrong tho..

Comment: I tried with multi-worded strings and it seems to have worked as expected with the below solution. I think this is because the delimiter is explicitly defined as `\t` for the CSV module (the input file was tab-delimited to begin with). So the spaces in the string are treated as part of a word.

Comment: I missed your file was tab delimited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pseudo-code has lots of issues (not talking about syntax issues, but logical issues).

I would use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for this. Simply read each row, split the first columns based on `';'` , if there are no `';'` you would get a list of one element back, if there are `';'` you would get the split list back, and then write it back to the other csv by using that value with the `row[1]` (second element of the row).

Example -

```
with open('colors_in.txt', 'r') as src, open('colors_out.txt', 'w') as dest:
    reader = csv.reader(src,delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(dest,delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        for col1 in row[0].split(';'):
            writer.writerow([col1,row[1]])
```

Comment: Awesome! This definitely did the trick.  I'm on a Windows machine, so I edited `r` and `w` to `rt` and `wt` and also added `newline = ''` so that my output didn't have empty lines in between the rows.